# How do I get out of the spiked ceiling room?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

The room with the spiky ceiling that comes down on top of you is so confusing! How do I get out alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 or four (not sure) red dots on the corners of the ceiling. You need to shoot them to stop the ceiling from falling.

Comment: The ceiling has been killing me for weeks! Not many people would believe how many impaled Leons I had to go through.